# How to find all unique values for specific key in array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of javascript objects and I am trying to get an array of all unique values for a specific property in each object. I tried to do this using reduce(), my example code is below, but it results in an error that it "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')" even though I provided an initial value of an empty array. The intended result is an array with

```
['New York', 'San Francisco', 'Chicago', 'Los Angeles']
```

The end goal is to create a bar graph with the cities on the X-axis and the calculated average wage for each city on the Y-axis, so I need the unique list of cities. Is there a way to avoid this error, or a better way to do this altogether?

```js
const employees= [
 {id: 0, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '15'}, 
 {id: 1, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '18'}, 
 {id: 2, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '16'}, 
 {id: 3, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '14'}, 
 {id: 4, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '12'}, 
 {id: 5, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '15'}, 
 {id: 6, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '18'}, 
 {id: 7, city: 'Los Angeles', wagePerHour: '10'}
];
const cities = employees.reduce((foundValues, nextEmployee) => {
 if(! foundValues.includes(nextEmployee.city)) {
  foundValues.push(nextEmployee.city);
 }
}, []);
```

Comment: Your `reduce` function doesn't return anything. Noting that `reduce` may not be the best approach if you're also filtering.

Answer (score 5):

An even simpler way would be to extract all the cities names and use the Set function to build a unique array:

```js
const employees = [{ id: 0, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '15' }, { id: 1, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '18' }, { id: 2, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '16' }, { id: 3, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '14' }, {  id: 4, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '12' }, { id: 5, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '15' }, {  id: 6, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '18' }, { id: 7, city: 'Los Angeles', wagePerHour: '10' }]

let cities = [... new Set(employees.map(x=>x.city))];

console.log(cities);
```

Answer (score 3):

With `Array#reduce` you have to return the updated `previousValue`. The easiest way to fix your code is to add `return foundValues`, which you could re-write as:

```
const cities = employees.reduce((foundValues, nextEmployee) => 
    foundValues.includes(nextEmployee.city) ? 
    foundValues : foundValues.concat(nextEmployee.city), []
);
```

However, you're free to explore other more efficient approaches, especially with the use of `Array#map` and `[...new Set()]`

```js
const employees= [
 {id: 0, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '15'}, 
 {id: 1, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '18'}, 
 {id: 2, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '16'}, 
 {id: 3, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '14'}, 
 {id: 4, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '12'}, 
 {id: 5, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '15'}, 
 {id: 6, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '18'}, 
 {id: 7, city: 'Los Angeles', wagePerHour: '10'}
];
const cities = employees.reduce((foundValues, nextEmployee) => {
   if(!foundValues.includes(nextEmployee.city)) {
      foundValues.push(nextEmployee.city);
   }
   return foundValues;
}, []);

console.log( cities );
```

**`rewrite`**

```js
const employees= [
 {id: 0, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '15'}, 
 {id: 1, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '18'}, 
 {id: 2, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '16'}, 
 {id: 3, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '14'}, 
 {id: 4, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '12'}, 
 {id: 5, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '15'}, 
 {id: 6, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '18'}, 
 {id: 7, city: 'Los Angeles', wagePerHour: '10'}
];
const cities = employees.reduce((foundValues, nextEmployee) => 
    foundValues.includes(nextEmployee.city) ? 
    foundValues : foundValues.concat(nextEmployee.city), []
);

console.log( cities );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the accumulator for the next iteration or as result.

```js
const
    employees = [{ id: 0, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '15' }, { id: 1, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '18' }, { id: 2, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '16' }, { id: 3, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '14' }, {  id: 4, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '12' }, { id: 5, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '15' }, {  id: 6, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '18' }, { id: 7, city: 'Los Angeles', wagePerHour: '10' }],
    cities = employees.reduce((foundValues, nextEmployee) => {
        if (!foundValues.includes(nextEmployee.city)) {
            foundValues.push(nextEmployee.city);
        }
        return foundValues;
    }, []);

console.log(cities);
```

A shorter approach takes a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with mapped cities for the constructor.

```js
const
    employees = [{ id: 0, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '15' }, { id: 1, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '18' }, { id: 2, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '16' }, { id: 3, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '14' }, {  id: 4, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '12' }, { id: 5, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '15' }, {  id: 6, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '18' }, { id: 7, city: 'Los Angeles', wagePerHour: '10' }],
    cities = Array.from(new Set(employees.map(({ city }) => city)));

console.log(cities);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`mapping`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the data to get an array of city names and putting them into a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to dedupe it might be a cleaner approach.

```js
const employees=[{id:0,city:"New York",wagePerHour:"15"},{id:1,city:"San Francisco",wagePerHour:"18"},{id:2,city:"New York",wagePerHour:"16"},{id:3,city:"Chicago",wagePerHour:"14"},{id:4,city:"Chicago",wagePerHour:"12"},{id:5,city:"San Francisco",wagePerHour:"15"},{id:6,city:"New York",wagePerHour:"18"},{id:7,city:"Los Angeles",wagePerHour:"10"}];

const cities = new Set(employees.map(obj => obj.city));

console.log([...cities]);
```

Additional documentation

- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Set

```
const employees = [
{ id: 0, city: "New York", wagePerHour: "15" },
{ id: 1, city: "San Francisco", wagePerHour: "18" },
{ id: 2, city: "New York", wagePerHour: "16" },
{ id: 3, city: "Chicago", wagePerHour: "14" },
{ id: 4, city: "Chicago", wagePerHour: "12" },
{ id: 5, city: "San Francisco", wagePerHour: "15" },
{ id: 6, city: "New York", wagePerHour: "18" },
{ id: 7, city: "Los Angeles", wagePerHour: "10" },
];

const uniqueCities = [...new Set(employees.map((employee) => employee.city))];    
 console.log(uniqueCities); // [ 'New York', 'San Francisco', 'Chicago', 'Los Angeles' ]
```

Or you can use feature of Object in JavaScript as well

```
const uniqueCities = {};
cities = employees.map((employee) => {
uniqueCities[employee.city] = "";
return;
 });

console.log(Object.keys(uniqueCities )); // [ 'New York', 'San Francisco', 'Chicago', 'Los Angeles' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The excellent answers already provided are accurate and to-the-point in addressing what precisely is required. This one, deviates from those in order to achieve the *end goal*.

> The end goal is to create a bar graph with the cities on the X-axis
> and the calculated average wage for each city on the Y-axis

Creating two separate arrays, one with x-axis values and then a separate one with y-axis values may be accomplished quicker by combining both the required logic into the same `.reduce()` iteration.

```js
// this method directly gets the x-axis and y-axis info required
const getXYaxisData = arr => (
  Object.values(
    arr.reduce(                           // this '.reduce' provides an object
      (fin, {city, wagePerHour}) => ({
        ...fin,
        [city]: {
          city,                           // object has props 'city', 'wagePerHour', 'count'
          wagePerHour: (
            (fin[city]?.wagePerHour ?? 0) +
            +wagePerHour
          ),
          count: (fin[city]?.count ?? 0) + 1
        }
      }),
      {}
    )
  ).map(                                    // this '.map' transforms the 'values' of the object
    ({city, wagePerHour, count}) => ({
      xAxis: city,
      yAxis: (wagePerHour/count).toFixed(2)
    })
  )
);


const employees= [
 {id: 0, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '15'}, 
 {id: 1, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '18'}, 
 {id: 2, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '16'}, 
 {id: 3, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '14'}, 
 {id: 4, city: 'Chicago', wagePerHour: '12'}, 
 {id: 5, city: 'San Francisco', wagePerHour: '15'}, 
 {id: 6, city: 'New York', wagePerHour: '18'}, 
 {id: 7, city: 'Los Angeles', wagePerHour: '10'}
];

const result = getXYaxisData(employees);
// console.log('combined-result: ', result);
console.log('x-axis array: ', result.map(({xAxis}) => xAxis));
console.log('y-axis array: ', result.map(({yAxis}) => yAxis));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

The above answer provides both x-axis and y-axis data.